# C# Copy one record from one dictionary to another

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I need to copy one record from one dictionary to another, only one. I have tried the below, It doesn't copy one but everything due to that its in the loop. And I need to check if the key is not already copied over to the second dictionary that's why I looped over the first dictionary.

```
foreach (int key in firstDict.Keys) 
    {
        if (!secondDict.ContainsKey(key))
            secondDict.Add(key, firstDict[key]);
        else {break;}
    }
```

Please help, should you require more info please let me know.

Comment: You will have to decide. If you want to copy *one* entry, you need to know its key. If you already know why *all* entries are copied, why don't you fix it? To check whether the record hasn't been copied, just use `ContainsKey`. A dictionary is not a list - every key can occur only once.

Comment: Do you want to copy a single entry, but any entry you mean ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want the foreach to stop if any key from first dict is already in the second dictionary? (cause that is what the `else` will do)

Comment: Yes @SirajMansour any entry but at the moment without knowing the key value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (int key in firstDict.Keys) 
{
    if (!secondDict.ContainsKey(key))
      {
        secondDict.Add(key, firstDict[key]);
        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Which copies only the first entry not in the second dictionary. If that's what the OP wants...

Comment: Thank you duDE now this works like magic. My problem was not breaking the loop that is why I was copying multiple records.

Answer (score 3):

A tiny bit more efficient than the others answers already posted (saves one dictionary lookup).

```
foreach(var kvp in firstDict)
{
    if(!secondDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
    {
        secondDict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
        break;
    }
}
```

And if you're familiar with linq you may want to avoid the whole `foreach ... break` pattern. That pattern is pretty ugly and more importantly confusing: it looks like you want to copy everything when you really want to copy just one. Your question itself is proof of how confusing it is: if you don't get a pattern that should be simple right, that probably means the pattern is not very good. The following will do the work, and it's crystal clear it will only add ONE (at most) entry to the second dictionary.

```
var missingEntry = firstDict
    // cast beacause KeyValuePair is a struct and I want to detect the case where there is no missing entry
    .Cast<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>?>()
    .FirstOrDefault(kvp => !secondDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key));

// check whether there truely is a missing entry.
if (missingEntry != null)
{
    secondDict[missingEntry.Key] = missingEntry.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have the key of that row in a certain variable that i will call `key`. here for example I'll set its value to 3.

```
int key = 3;

if (!secondDict.ContainsKey(key))
            secondDict.Add(key, firstDict[key]);
```

EDIT: 
If you want only any single entry that is not present in present in secondDict:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, MyValueType> kvp in firstDict) //Replace MyValueType with the real value type in firstDict
{
    if (!secondDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
      {
        secondDict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        break;
      }
}
```

Comment: No I don't have the key on a variable I'm taking the key from the firstDict, That is why I'm looping over it.

Comment: so you want any single entry that is not in secondDict !?

Comment: @Lord-David check the added EDIT

Answer (score 1):

remove the else clause

```
foreach (int key in firstDict.Keys) 
{
    if (!secondDict.ContainsKey(key)) {
        secondDict.Add(key, firstDict[key]);
        break;
    }
}
```